# How to reconstruct an element, adding an element

Tags: xquery

Here is the element I want to reconstruct:

```
<element>
    <1></1>
    <2></2>
    <3>
        <3a>
            <3a1>
            </3a1>
        </3a>
    </3>
</element>
```

I would like to add an element (`<4>`) right before the end of `<element>`. This is what I have tried:

```
 return <element> element/*, <4>data</4> </element>
```

But what I get back is `<4>` inserted like so:

```
<element>
    <1></1>
    <2></2>
    <3>
        <3a>
            <3a1>
                **<4>data</4>**
            </3a1>
        </3a>
    </3>
</element>
```

How do I acheive this:

```
<element>
    <1></1>
    <2></2>
    <3>
        <3a>
            <3a1>
            </3a1>
        </3a>
    </3>
    <4>data</4>
</element>
```

Comment: FYI for XML to be valid, element names must be valid QNames, which cannot start with a number.

Comment: Also, assuming this were valid, the code you present here should would return your expected output, so I suspect your example does not reflect the problem.

Comment: @wst, for the XML to be valid it would require a DTD or schema (which is not available here) – without it can just be well-formed.

Comment: @OP: What have you tried, can you use XQuery Update or do you have to reconstruct the element?

Comment: @JensErat With or without schema/DTD, element names must be valid QNames. Also, it's not possible to get the output OP suggests with the code presented here...something is clearly missing from this question.

Comment: Yes, but valid names are not sufficient for valid XML documents. Just wanted to clarify this difference.

Comment: Sorry about that. the element names were just to get the idea across. They are not the actual elements I'm working with.

Comment: @wst You're right. I just tried this in a less complicated environment and it worked as expected. Something else funky must be going on elsewhere in the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the extra element in the following way:

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare function local:insert-as-last-child($node as node(), $new-content as node()) as node() {
     element {node-name($node)}
                {
                $node/@*
                ,
                for $child in $node/node()
                    return $child
                ,
                $new-content
                }
};

let $input :=
<elements>
    <element-1/>
    <element-2/>
    <element-3>
        <element-3a>
            <element-3aelement-1> </element-3aelement-1>
        </element-3a>
    </element-3>
</elements>

return 
    local:insert-as-last-child($input, <element-4>data</element-4>)    xquery version "3.0";

declare function local:insert-as-last-child($node as node(), $new-content as node()) as node() {
     element {node-name($node)}
                {
                $node/@*
                ,
                for $child in $node/node()
                    return $child
                ,
                $new-content
                }
};

let $input :=
<elements>
    <element-1/>
    <element-2/>
    <element-3>
        <element-3a>
            <element-3aelement-1> </element-3aelement-1>
        </element-3a>
    </element-3>
</elements>

return 
    local:insert-as-last-child($input, <element-4>data</element-4>)
```

For more options, see the [XQuery Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Filtering_Nodes).